# Unresolved import of external library with properties file in classpath

Tags: java, import, classpath, properties-file, usb4java

I'm working with usb4java at the high level following this demo: http://usb4java.org/quickstart/javax-usb.html. My issue is that we need javax.usb.properties in the classpath, so I've put it in the src directory. I've also loaded up the .jars into a lib directory and added them to the referenced libraries. After all of this when importing "javax.usb.*" I'm getting an import cannot be resolved error and none of the types are accepted.

Note: the properties file is populated with: "javax.usb.services = org.usb4java.javax.Services" as instructed.

Thoughts?

Comment: which IDE and OS being used? This looks more of a class path OR IDE issue than API itself. If using Eclipse, see if this helps , [Eclipse Import cannot be resolved error](http://blog.sherifmansour.com/?p=207)

Comment: I realized that I left that out right as I was falling asleep.

Comment: Thanks @Sabir_Khan I agree it's probably eclipse, but I've tried all of those solutions.

Comment: Stupid editing restrictions: OS: Windows, IDE: Eclipse

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to add to the CLASSPATH also the JSR080 (javax.usb API). Where the javax.usb interface is defined. You can download from here: http://javax-usb.sourceforge.net/

I have checked and it looks the javax.usb API is included under lib folder in the usb4java-javax distribution: http://nexus.ailis.de/content/groups/public/org/usb4java/usb4java-javax/1.2.0/usb4java-javax-1.2.0.zip it is called usb-api.jar

Then make sure the `javax.usb.properties` file is on the root of your application CLASSPATH.

Comment: Wow....I feel really stupid. When it said it used JSR080 I assumed that it was packaged with it. Downloaded it, and added that to the path and it's all good now.